# $ \int_{0}^{1}|f(x)|^{2}dx \leq \bigg|\text{Re}\int_{0}^{1}xf(x)\overline{f^{\prime}(x)}dx\bigg|. $

Tags: analysis, inequality, sobolev-spaces

> Consider $f \in L^{2}(0,1)$ and $f^{\prime} \in L^{2}(0,1)$ with $f(1) =0$. Then

> $$
> \int_{0}^{1}|f(x)|^{2}dx \leq \bigg|\text{Re}\int_{0}^{1}xf(x)\overline{f^{\prime}(x)}dx\bigg|.
> $$

Note that
$$
(x[f(x)]^{2})^{\prime} = f(x)^{2} + 2xf(x)f^{\prime}(x)
$$
Soon, how $f(1) = 0$, then
$$
\int_{0}^{1}|f(x)|^{2}dx \leq 2\bigg|\int_{0}^{1}xf(x)\overline{f^{\prime}(x)}dx\bigg|.
$$
And now? And $\text{Re}$?

Comment: @MartinR Thank you very much.

Comment: Use integration by parts

Comment: You need to take the derivative of $x|f(x)|^2$ not of $x(f(x))^2$, then the 'Re' appears naturally.

Comment: You probably mean $ L^{2}(0, 1)$ ...

Comment: @daw why naturally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $|f|^2 =  f\,\overline f$, just replace the first equation in your reasoning by
$$
(x \,|f|^2)' = |f|^2 + x\, f' \,\overline f + x\,f\,\overline{f'} = |f|^2 + 2\,x\,\mathrm{Re}(f\,\overline{f'}).
$$

Comment: Thank you very much